# Explain me what this array subtract term called

Tags: javascript

variable A is working but variable B shows NaN, and why?

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]+[5,6,7,8];
var b = [1,2,3,4]-[5,6,7,8];
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a concatenation operator, which is not defined for use on arrays. The engine is converting your arrays to a string, than concatenating them

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn not exactly, in his case the result is a string, with `concat` it would be an array

Comment: Ahh you are right... I thought the `+` was concat shorthand. I never use this so I guess I didn't know...

Comment: String concatenation is correct.   `[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]` => `"1,2,34,5,6"`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript typecast any variable based on operator. For `+` operator array is getting converted to string which is `"1,2,3,4" + "5,6,7,8"`
For `-` operator array is getting converted to number which would result in `NaN`.

Comment: Converting an array to a string does not include the square braces. It becomes `"1,2,3,4" + "5,6,7,8"`

Answer (score 0):

These operators are called Unary Plus and Unary Negation.

UP tries to convert the operand into a `Number`. `Array` converts into `String` when it is longer than 1 length, then the resulting operands are Unary Plus(ed), which, if one of them is a `String` concatenates both into a `String`.

UN does not concatenate so all those steps are skipped, if it doesn't convert to a `Number` than it is a `NaN`.

Here's some example of what happens:

```
[1]+[2]
 "12"

+[1,2,3]
 NaN

+[1]
 1

[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]
 "1,2,34,5,6"

[1,2,3]+[4,5,6,7]
 "1,2,34,5,6,7"

[1]+[4,5,6,7]
 "14,5,6,7"

Number([1])+Number([4])
 5

Number([1])+[4]
 "14"
```